# Bash grep sth. then to find the position

Tags: bash, grep, line

I've long been wondering about this question;
say I first try to grep some lines from a file:

```
cat 101127_2.bam |grep 'TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA'
```

Then it'll pop out the whole line containing this string.
However, can we use some simple bash code to locate at which line this string locates? (100th? 1000th?...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -n 'TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA' 101127_2.bam
```

I found it using `man grep` and writing `/line number`

// EDIT: Thanks @Keith Thompson I'm editing post from `cat file | grep -n pattern` to `grep -n pattern file`, I was in a hurry sorry

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
cat 101127_2.bam |grep -n 'TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA'
```

Comment: Better: `grep -n 'TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA' 101127_2.bam `.

Comment: Oh no! I was in such a hurry to answer the question I fell prey to [Useless Use of Cat](http://www.partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). I am suitably humbled.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you too:

```
sed '/TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA/=;d' 101127_2.bam
```

or

```
sed -n '/TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA/=' 101127_2.bam
```

The above solutions only output the matching line numbers, to see the lines matched too:

```
sed '/TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA/!d;=' 101127_2.bam
```

or

```
sed -n '/TGATTACTTGCTTTATTTTAGTGTTTAATTTGTTCTTTTCTAATAA/{=;p}' 101127_2.bam
```